# Swift: Clicking on a tableViewCell prints the wrong index number

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to see if the click of the tableviewcell corresponds with the right data. So for example I am clicking on the first cell I get nothing on the output console and if I click on a different cell I get the wrong index number of the cell.

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ToDoListViewController: UITableViewController {

    let itemArray = ["Japan", "Korea", "Vietnam"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: Tableview Data Source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return itemArray.count
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let reuseIdentifier = "ToDoItemCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: TableView Delegate Methods

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `didSelectRowAt` instead of `didDeselectRowAt` should resolver your problem.

Comment: @ReyBruno thanks, worked :)